# OpenGL VertexArray Data "Retention"?

Tags: opengl, vertex-buffer-object

After calling `glVertexAttribPointer` to associate data of the currently bound vertex array with data from the currently bound `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`, I mentioned that I can simply delete the used buffer without it affecting the rendering.

What actually happens with the data within the buffer when calling `glVertexAttribPointer`? It seems like the data from the buffer actually get's copied into another memory location that the vertex array uses.

Answer (score 5):

[Deleting an OpenGL object](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Object#Object_Creation_and_Destruction) is merely a suggestion. Deleting an object will unbind the object from any binding point it is currently bound to. However, buffer objects are not "bound" to VAOs. They are *attached* to VAOs.

When you call `glVertexAttrib*Pointer`, you attach a buffer object to the VAO. The buffer object to be attached is the one bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`. Unbinding that buffer, or even flat-out deleting it, will *not* undo the attachment.

And an OpenGL object [will continue to exist so long as it is *attached* to a container object](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Object#Deletion_orphaning).